# Load data before rendering component in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I tried to recuperate data from service before rendering my component but i have this error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataEntries' of undefined

this is my code:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.route.params.subscribe((params:Params)=>{
  this.ActivityId=params['id']
 })
 this.activityInstanceIdentifier= {
  "class":"eu.w4.engine.client.bpmn.w4.runtime.ActivityInstanceIdentifier",
  "id":this.ActivityId
 }
 this.activityInstanceAttachement= {
  "class":"eu.w4.engine.client.bpmn.w4.runtime.ActivityInstanceAttachment",
  "dataEntriesAttached":true
 }
this.activityService.getActivityInstance(this.sessionService.getPrincipal(),
                                         this.activityInstanceIdentifier,
                                         this.activityInstanceAttachement)
                                        .subscribe((ActivityInstance)=>{
                                          this.dataInstance=ActivityInstance                                 
                                        });
 }

forms = [
 {
  dataEditionMode:DataEditionMode.DISPLAY,
  name:"demande",
  editedInstance:this.dataInstance["dataEntries"]["demande"]["value"],
  component:DemandeFormComponent,
  multiple:false
 }
]
```

I tried to use 'resolve' also but it doesn't work , any help ?

Comment: Async issue : you should move your forms definition inside your subscribe callback.

Comment: If you need to retrieve data from a service before the component is loaded you can use a [resolver](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data), it loads data from your service before the component is rendered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> JS is Asynchronous. Which means it won't wait for any I/O request to
>   get complete and will keep executing next lines of code.

In you case   `getActivityInstance` method is asynchronous hence  JS won't wait for it to get complete and it will execute the next line . Hence

`editedInstance :  this.dataInstance["dataEntries"]["demande"]["value"]`  gets executed before service returns the data (that time `dataInstance` will be `undefined` if you haven't initialized it) .

Modify your code like this  :

```
this.activityService.getActivityInstance(this.sessionService.getPrincipal(),
                                         this.activityInstanceIdentifier,
                                         this.activityInstanceAttachement)
                                        .subscribe((ActivityInstance)=>{
                                          this.dataInstance=ActivityInstance;

 forms = [
 {
  dataEditionMode:DataEditionMode.DISPLAY,
  name:"demande",
  editedInstance:this.dataInstance["dataEntries"]["demande"]["value"],
  component:DemandeFormComponent,
  multiple:false
 }
]
  });
```