# How do I automatically run a function when the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, function, onload

I have a function called "getData" that needs to be executed in order to display certain information. I want it to run automatically but at the moment it only displays the data after clicking a button that activates the function - see (component.html):

```html
<button (click)="getData()">Fetch Data</button>
```

I already tried to insert the function in ngOnInit() in the component.ts-file:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.getData()
  }
```

and tried onload in the component.html file:

```html
<p onload="getData();">component works!</p>
```

... both did not lead to the needed result

This is how the code looks like (I basically get the data from an API Call and select an item with a certain id)
component.ts

```
/*some code*/
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit {
  public data: any = []
  public selected: any = []
  constructor(
    public http: HttpClient, 
    public route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  getData(){
    const person_id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('person_id');
    const url ='http://localhost:4000/api/allpeople';
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(data => this.data = data);
    this.selected=this.data.find(item=>
      {
        if(item['person_id']===person_id)
          {
            return true;
          }
        return false;
      });
    console.log(person_id, this.selected);
    return this.selected;
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getData()
  }
```

component.html

```html
<h1>{{selected.title}}</h1>
{{selected.person_id}}
```

When loading the page the console logs the following Error
"Cannot read property 'title' of undefined" 
and the error message refers to this line: `<h1>{{selected.title}}</h1>`

But when I click the button it logs the data as it is supposed to.

How can I let this automatically happen?

Comment: I'm not familiar with angular. How do you pass the data to the template engine?

Comment: @mplungjan While there are questions related to [loading data before rendering in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55239213/load-data-before-rendering-component-in-angular-7) all/most of those results are for anuglarjs, personally I hate the angular tab as there are now so many versions, it's hard to tell which one someone is using

Comment: @George then something like https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bangular%5D+execute+page+load

Comment: You'd need to post more code. You're initializing selected to an array [] but trying to access an object.

Comment: @Flignats: thanks for the advice - added further code above

Comment: If you want a component to be rendered only when you data is there, you could have a look at the [route resolver](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) which provides data to an explicit route and only render the corresponding components when the data is there. If you're not using routes you have to go with a switch as posted by @Flignats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngOnInit()` is the right place, when you want to call the method onload. If the data is async 'selected' can still be undefined when the template is rendered. To avoid the error you can wrap the block with a condition like @Flignats did or simply add a `?` like

```
  <h1>{{selected?.title}}</h1>
  {{selected?.person_id}}
```

The `?.` stops evaluating when `selected` is `null` or `undefined`.

You are assigning the data outside the subscription. It should be like this:

```
getData(){
...
this.http.get(url).subscribe(data => {
  this.data = data;
  this.selected=this.data.find(item=>
    {
      if(item['person_id']===person_id)
        {
          return true;
        }
      return false;
    });
    console.log(person_id, this.selected);
  });
}
```

Comment: You can also put regular conditional logic within the double curly selector, like so `{{ selected.title || 'there is no title' }}`

Comment: It stops the error mesage from appearing - but still does not evaluate the function after the rendering of the template is finished - so the data does not appear automatically but only after clicking the button I mentioned bevore (same for @JDunken)

Comment: Where does the data for selected come from?
Is the method `getData()` ever called when initializing (when called in onInit())?

Comment: i have the method getData() in OnInit() - basically I get the data from an API Call and store a single specific Item in ```selected``` - see the recently extended code in the question above

Comment: Check how you assign the person to `this.selected`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Error "Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"

This is because when the expression is ran in the template, at that time the data has not loaded and it is undefined.

Put the call back into the `ngOnInit()` and wrap the expression in an ngIf statement.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="selected">
  <h1>{{selected.title}}</h1>
  {{selected.person_id}}
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I figured the same cause - unfortunately it still does not work after trying your solution - what exactly is the purpose of  ```*ngIf```?

Comment: `selected` is the variable declared in the component's ts file that is available in the component's html file. `*ngIf` is an Angular structural directive, it dynamically builds html elements.

Comment: @Flignats thanks for the advice - will add further code above

Comment: I tried it but it still does not work - only after clicking the button I get the wanted result

Answer (score 0):

Use `$scope` and call a function at the beginning of your controller, like this

```
$scope.init = function () {
   $scope.title = "title";
   $scope.person_id = 2;
};

$scope.init();
```

The controller is automatically loaded with the page, and the $scope in this case can make what you want ($scope.init() is automatically called if you don't wrap it in other functions)

Comment: Do you mean the component.html file with "controller"?

Comment: I mean the AngularJS controller you associated to the html file...you can usually see it with `<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">`...the ng-controller part links to your controller

Comment: Sorry but I am still not sure where exactly to put this code

Comment: It seems to be an angular > v2 problem not angularjs. There is no $scope. Something similar or equivalent would be the ngOnInit() method.